# Undefined Return Value

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get data from a MySQL-database using JS and PHP (without jquery or ajax) 
But I keep getting the "undefined Return Value Error".

It's my first time programming in JS and PHP.

```
url: "../PHP/Kassensystem.php?productname="+productname
```

JS:

```
function getProduct(url) {

let product;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        product = request.responseText;
    }
};
request.send(null);

return product;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$productname = $_GET['productname'];
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'allgolddb';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$prodctInfos = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '$productname'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $prodctInfos[] = $row;
}

$json_array = json_encode($prodctInfos);
return $json_array;
?>
```

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL injection attacks** - use parameterised statements to secure your data.

Comment: Side note: _"without jquery or ajax"_ - You're still using Ajax. That's what you're using `new XMLHttpRequest()` for.

Comment: Never combine [javascript] and [mysql] in your question. It's two completely different realms that **never** meet. So it's either [php] and [mysql] or [javascript] and [php]

Comment: The issue is most likely that you have `return $json_array;` while you should output the data using: `echo $json_array;`. Using `return` in this context won't actually do anything.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh that was an editing error, ok I will try with echo ... did not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `open` method you've set 3rd param to `true` so your `request.send` will be executed asynchronously. And as with every asynchronous JavaScript, by the time your code execution reaches `return product` `product` is still `undefined` and hence the error.

You can set the 3rd param to `false` to make it synchronous and your code will work (atleast working in firefox so far):

```
request.open("GET", url, false);
```

However the sync option is deprecated. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#Parameters)

> Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive to the user experience and should be avoided; in fact, many browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely. Synchronous requests are permitted in Workers.

As for working asynchronously, you'll have to consume within the callback to `onload` method:

```
request.onload = function () {
  if (request.status == 200) {
    product = request.responseText;
    console.log(product) // consume here
  }
};
```

You could also use `Promise`, optionally with `async/await`. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to work with asynchronous code.